# Pandas: How to display inclusive starting and ending bin labels

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
bins = np.arange(0, 189, 6)
bins
```

returns

```
array([  0,   6,  12,  18,  24,  30,  36,  42,  48,  54,  60,  66,  72,
        78,  84,  90,  96, 102, 108, 114, 120, 126, 132, 138, 144, 150,
       156, 162, 168, 174, 180, 186])
```

which I then use to categorize a column of differences

```
df['diffs'] = pd.cut(df['differences'], bins =bins)
df.day_diff_range.value_counts()
```

resulting in this:

```
(0, 6]        1744
(6, 12]       1199
(12, 18]      1003
(18, 24]       934
(24, 30]       815
(30, 36]       754
etc
```

However, I want the ranges to be like so: [0, 6], [7, 13], [14, 20] and so on where both points of each bin are inclusive and the next bin adds 1 to the max of the previous bin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding **custom labels** to a binned DataFrame, can be accomplished by passing the `labels` argument into the `pd.cut()` method. [Documentation reference here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html).

In the example below, the `labels` are built using list comprehension and `zip` to offset of the bins, for simplicity and clarity.

Additionally, I've increased the bin size to 7 (from 6), and added the `right=False` argument to ensure proper bin alignment.

```
import pandas as pd
import random

# Create a random set of testing values.
random.seed(73)
vals = [random.randint(1,188) for _ in range(1000)]
# Create a testing DataFrame.
df = pd.DataFrame({'vals': vals})

# Create bins and bin labels.
bins = range(0, 189, 7)
labels = [f'[{a},{b-1}]' for a, b in zip(bins, bins[1:])]

# Apply the bins and labels.
pd.cut(df['vals'], 
       bins=bins, 
       right=False, 
       labels=labels).value_counts().sort_index()
```

Example output:

```
[0,6]        32
[7,13]       39
[14,20]      28
...          ...
[161,167]    45
[168,174]    32
[175,181]    33
Name: vals, dtype: int64
```

Unlabeled output, for accuracy comparison. Produced using the same `pd.cut(...)` statement, *without* the `labels` argument.

```
[0, 7)        32
[7, 14)       39
[14, 21)      28
...           ...
[161, 168)    45
[168, 175)    32
[175, 182)    33
Name: vals, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Say I wanted to do the same thing but with dates, how would I go about doing so? For example, my first date is 2022-01-01 and my last date is 2022-09-01 and I want to create week long bins (ie: 2022/01/01-2022/01/06, 2022/01/07-2022/01/13, etc).

Comment: Same principal really.  At this point, the labels are just strings, so you can manipulate them as you please.  There is no direct link between the bins and labels, it’s just a 1 to 1 mapping. Here is a link to the `pandas.date_range` docs, which might be helpful.  [Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html)